# Is this true in floating-point arithmetic: If a,b are not +inf, -inf or NAN, a=b <=> a-b=0

Tags: floating-point

Suppose a,b are two 64-bit floating-point that are not +inf, -inf or NAN, can I claim that:

> a = b if and only if  a - b = 0

If yes, why it always holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true (assuming the use of IEEE-754 floating point, which is ubiquitous on desktop architectures). A much stronger and more generally useful statement, known as Sterbenz's Theorem, says that if two numbers are within a factor of 2 of each other, their difference can be exactly represented; your statement is a special case of that.

An easier way to see it is to consider how things could go wrong. If `a != b` but `a - b` rounds to zero, then `a` and `b` must have been *extremely* close together. In fact, the difference between them would have to be less than half the smallest subnormal number. But that's clearly less than the distance between adjacent subnormal numbers! Trying to find two unequal floating point numbers whose difference rounded to zero would be like trying to find two unequal *integers* whose difference rounded to zero.

Comment: The question does not specify IEEE-754 arithmetic is used. Floating-point arithmetic does not always include subnormal values.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not true in general.

It is true if the floating-point arithmetic fully conforms to IEEE 754, and it may be true for non-IEEE-754 arithmetic if it uses subnormal values or gradual underflow.

However, IEEE 754 is not always used in full. It is not uncommon for processors to have modes in which they change subnormal results and/or subnormal inputs to zero, and operating systems (or program initialization code) may enable such modes by default for performance. In such modes, subtracting two very small normal numbers produces zero instead of the subnormal result that would be proper under IEEE 754 rules.

As for why it holds, consider the general format of floating-point numbers. Details vary from one floating-point system to another, but generally a floating-point number is *s* • *N* • *b*<sup>*e*</sup>, where *s* (for sign) is +1 or −1, *N* (called the significand) is a non-negative integer, *b* is a base, and *e* is an exponent. *b* is fixed, and typically there are restrictions on the ranges of *N* and *e*. We will also assume the floating-point arithmetic returns exact mathematical results when they are representable and, when they are not, returns a user’s choice of the nearest representable value or the nearer value in a particular direction.

Commonly *N* is a fixed number of base-*b* digits, such as 24 bits for a base-two format, in which case 0 ≤ *N* < *b*<sup>*d*</sup>, where *d* is the number of digits. Alternately, it might be limited to some other maximum, so that 0 ≤ *N* < *N*<sub>max</sub>. (For example, Microsoft has a decimal format in which *b* is 10, but *N* is a 96-bit number.) In either case if this is the only restriction on *N*, then `a = b` iff `a-b == 0` holds. To see this, consider two positive floating-point numbers (the cases for other signs follow simply) *N*<sub>0</sub> • *b*<sup>*e*<sub>0</sub></sup> and *N*<sub>1</sub> • *b*<sup>*e*<sub>1</sub></sup>. Without loss of generality, assume *e*<sub>0</sub> ≤ *e*<sub>1</sub>. If they are equal, the mathematical result is zero, and, since this is representable, the computed floating-point result is zero. If they are not equal, the mathematical result is (*N*<sub>0</sub> − *N*<sub>1</sub> • *b*<sup>*e*<sub>1</sub>−*e*<sub>0</sub></sup>) • *b*<sup>*e*<sub>0</sub></sup>. The term (*N*<sub>0</sub> − *N*<sub>1</sub> • *b*<sup>*e*<sub>1</sub>−*e*<sub>0</sub></sup>) may be positive or negative, which can be handled by setting the sign of the result, and it might be greater than or equal to *N*<sub>max</sub>. Whatever the case may be, can be the computed result be zero? No, because *N*<sub>0</sub> − *N*<sub>1</sub> • *b*<sup>*e*<sub>1</sub>−*e*<sub>0</sub></sup> is an integer, so, if it is not 0, it is at least 1 in magnitude, and therefore one of the representable values +1 • *b*<sup>*e*<sub>0</sub></sup> or −1 • *b*<sup>*e*<sub>0</sub></sup> is nearer to the mathematical result than 0 is, so 0 will never be chosen as the result of rounding the result to the nearest representable value.

Thus, for a floating-point system which allows any *N* such that 0 ≤ *N* < *N*<sub>max</sub>, and which uses some round-to-nearest/nearer method, the proposition holds. (As mentioned above, if the floating-point arithmetic uses a different method, such as one that rounds subnormal values to zero even though there are nearer representable values, the proposition does not hold.)

A problem arises in some floating-point systems because *N* is further constrained. A common requirement is that *N* must either be zero or must be normalized so that its leading digit is not zero, meaning that *N* = 0 or *b*<sup>*d*−1</sup> ≤ *N* < *b*<sup>*d*</sup>. Consider subtracting two numbers in such a system with the result (*N*<sub>0</sub> − *N*<sub>1</sub> • *b*<sup>*e*<sub>1</sub>−*e*<sub>0</sub></sup>) • *b*<sup>*e*<sub>0</sub></sup>. The term *N*<sub>0</sub> − *N*<sub>1</sub> • *b*<sup>*e*<sub>1</sub>−*e*<sub>0</sub></sup> might be smaller than *b*<sup>*d*−1</sup>. To deal with this, we desire to adjust the representation of the number by multiplying that term by *b* while dividing the *b*<sup>*e*<sub>0</sub></sup> term by *b*. But the exponent is bounded; we are only allowed to make it so small. If *e*<sub>0</sub> is too small, we might not be able to adjust the *N* term to fit in *b*<sup>*d*−1</sup> ≤ *N* < *b*<sup>*d*</sup>. In this case, the exact mathematical result must be rounded to the nearest/nearer representable value, and this can result in 0 being produced. Thus, in a floating-point system that requires normalization in the *N* term, `a-b` can produce zero even when `a == b` is false.

IEEE-754 requires normalized significands when possible but allows significands to be non-normalized at the bottom of the exponent range. Thus, mathematically it behaves like a system with the requirement 0 ≤ *N* < *b*<sup>*d*</sup>, so it satisfies the proposition.

(Note: I have described the floating-point format as *s* • *N* • *b*<sup>*e*</sup> where *N* is an integer. Floating-point formats are also often described using *N* as a base-*b* number with *d* digits where there is a radix point after the first digit or before the first digit. In this case, *N* is not necessarily an integer but instead is an integer multiple of *b*<sup>1−*d*</sup> or *b*<sup>−*d*</sup>. The description is irrelevant because the mathematical behavior is the same, except that proofs have to talk about *N* being integer multiples of a power of *b* instead of being simple integers, and the bounds for the exponent *e* are shifted by 1−*d* or *d*.)

Comment: Very good answer (as usual), but
IMO another prerequisite is that `-0 == +0` as a floating point compare, as it is the case for fully IEEE-754.